# How to count study-years toward Polish law for Permanent Residency

Tags: immigration, residency, poland

I studied in Poland for 4 years. How many years count according to:

> Art. 212.1.   Do   5-letniego   okresu   pobytu   na   terytorium   Rzeczypospolitej Polskiej, o którym mowa w art. 211 ust. 1, zalicza się:
> 3)połowę okresu  pobytu  na  terytorium  Rzeczypospolitej  Polskiej – w przypadku cudzoziemca przebywającego na terytorium Rzeczypospolitej Polskiej:
> a) na  podstawie  wizy  wydanej  w celu,  o którym mowa w art. 60  ust. 1  pkt 9 lub 10, lub b) na podstawie zezwolenia, o którym mowa w art. 144 lub art. 187 pkt 1 lit. b
>
> > Article 212.1.  The 5-year period of stay in the territory of the Republic of Poland, referred to in Article 211 section 1, includes: 3) half of the period of stay in the territory of the Republic of Poland - in the case of a foreigner staying on the territory of the Republic of Poland: a) on the basis of a visa issued for the purpose for which  referred to in Article 60 (1) point 9 or 10, or b) on the basis of a permit referred to in Article 144 or Article 187 point 1 (b)

**AND**

> Art. 212.2. Do   5-letniego   okresu   pobytu   na   terytorium   Rzeczypospolitej   Polskiej, o którym mowa w art. 211 ust. 1, nie zalicza się pobytu cudzoziemca:
> 3) w okresie jego nauki na terytorium Rzeczypospolitej Polskiej;
>
> > Article 212.2. Up to the 5-year period of stay in the territory of the Republic of Poland, referred to in Article 211, paragraph 1, the stay of a foreigner shall not be included: 3) during the period of his / her education in the territory of the Republic of Poland;

http://isap.sejm.gov.pl/isap.nsf/download.xsp/WDU20130001650/U/D20131650Lj.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You count study period as 50%, so 2 years.

> "połowę okresu pobytu na terytorium Rzeczypospolitej Polskiej – w przypadku cudzoziemca przebywającego na terytorium Rzeczypospolitej Polskiej: a) na podstawie wizy wydanej w celu, o którym mowa w art. 60 ust. 1 pkt 9"

This article is what you should use:

> Art. 60 ust. 1 pkt 9
>
> > odbycia studiów pierwszego stopnia, studiów drugiego stopnia lub jednolitych
> > studiów magisterskich albo kształcenia się w szkole doktorskiej

It means Higher Education - Tertiary Education.

> Art. 212.2.
>
> > Do 5-letniego okresu pobytu na terytorium Rzeczypospolitej Polskiej, o którym mowa w art. 211 ust. 1, nie zalicza się pobytu cudzoziemca: 3) w okresie jego nauki na terytorium Rzeczypospolitej Polskiej;

It means Primary / Secondary Education.